# Split a single variable-multi character vector into chunks

Tags: r

Although simple, I couldn't find a robust solution.

I have a single variable-multi character vector (i.e. `"ABCDEFGHI"`), that I'm looking to split into a multi single-letter vector (i.e. `c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")`
).

Is there a single function capable of that? or should I put my effort into writing a function for that?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `strsplit` from `R`

```
strsplit(str1, "")[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"
```

---

In `python`, cast to `list`

```
list("ABCDEFGH")
#['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ABCDEFGHI"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stringr` function `str_split` as well

```
library(stringr)
str_split(str1, "", simplify = T)[1,]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `regmatches` and to match any `word` character using `\w` expression.

```
str <- "ABCDEFG"
regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\w",str))[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
```